# How to remove postgres database from heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

How to remove postgres database from heroku, which was created using the dev free plan.
https://postgres.heroku.com/databases

I tried using **heroku addons:remove --confirm --app salty-river-24**
but it says app not found. Is this the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created the database with the web UI on postgres.heroku.com, you need to navigate to it from https://postgres.heroku.com/databases , then click on the gear icon on the right. There should be a **destroy** link. If you don't see a destroy link, then you probably aren't the owner and lack privileges.

Comment: I don't see a gear icon on the right, I actually created them in the user interface on the above link (dev free option)

Comment: If you click to the database itself from postgres.heroku.com/databases you'll see information about it, including connection information etc. On the right is a gear. shown here: http://cl.ly/image/2n1I1g0q3g3n .  If you don't have a "destroy" link, then you don't have the right permissions

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 6):

First, check all the addons you have by running:

```
$ heroku addons
```

This lists all available addons (detailing name, plan, price and state). Here, note the detail provided next to the addon. For instance, you may see something like:

`heroku-postgresql (postgresql-cubic-88094)  hobby-dev  free   created └─ as DATABASE`

To delete this specific addon, run:

```
$ heroku addons:destroy postgresql-asymmetrical-03894
```

`postgresql-cubic-88094` is in brackets in the listed addon.

You will be asked to type in the name of your app or re-run the command using `--confirm <name-of-your-app>`. Do so and the addon will be deleted.

Confirm the addon is deleted by running:

```
$ heroku addons
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're missing the name of the add-on. Example:

```
$ heroku addons:remove heroku-postgresql:dev --app salty-river-24
```

Use `heroku addons --help` to view the help, or `heroku addons` to list the add-ons for your app.

Comment: Removing heroku-postgresql:dev on -a... failed
 !    App not found.

Comment: Is that the right name of the app?  Is it in the set of apps that you get when you type `heroku apps`?  Also, do you have the latest [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) installed?

Comment: heroku apps is not listing the postgres databases which I created. I am using the latest heroku toolbelt.

Comment: heroku addons
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.

Comment: Even heroku addons doesn't list anything for me, what am I missing.

Comment: @Rpj if you created this on postgres.heroku.com you wont have CLI access to it via it's name.